# 2xN grid in HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, reactjs

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Dropdown Menu</title>
    <style>
        .custom-box {
            background-color: #ff5733;
            padding: 20px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        }

        .box-title {
            font-size: 24px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #fff;
        }

        .box-content {
            margin-top: 10px;
            font-size: 18px;
            color: #333;
        }

        .custom-button {
            background-color: #ff8f33;
            color: #fff;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 5px;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

        .custom-button:hover {
            background-color: #ff5722;
        }

        .dropdown-content {
            display: none;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .dropdown-item {
            margin: 10px 0;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="custom-box">
        <div class="box-title">Dropdown Menu</div>
        <div class="box-content">
            Sample Text
        </div>
        <button class="custom-button" id="dropdown-button">Click Me</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content" id="dropdown-menu">
            <div class="dropdown-item">Item 1</div>
            <div class="dropdown-item">Item 2</div>
            <div class="dropdown-item">Item 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        const dropdownButton = document.getElementById('dropdown-button');
        const dropdownMenu = document.getElementById('dropdown-menu');

        dropdownButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            dropdownMenu.style.display = dropdownMenu.style.display === 'none' ? 'flex' : 'none';
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like it so the max number of boxes that can be displayed per row is 2, so it creates a 2x2 grid if I want to add 2 more link boxes, and so on. Right now, when I tried to add 2 more link boxes, it doesn't create a 2x2 effect, and I tried using `grid-template-columns` on the wrapper to wrap the link boxes so that it follows a grid template, using `display: flex` but it was not working as expected. Don't you need to add it to the `wrapper` class so it wraps all the link boxes in a certain manner (2x2 grid)?

I essentially want a 2xN grid format where N is the number of columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're better off using Grid layout on your wrapper. Something like this:

```css
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 10px;
}
```

Here's a quick demo:

```css
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 10px;
}
  
  .tilecontainer {
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 25px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .tilecontainer {
      font-size: 16px;
    }
  }
  
  .box {
    background-color: #0051a5;
    padding-right: 1em;
    padding-top: 1em;
    border-radius: 1em;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
    grid-template-columns: auto 1em;
    grid-template-areas: "sample plus" "extratext extratext";
  }
  
  .plus {
    grid-area: plus;
    background: linear-gradient(#0051a5 0 0), linear-gradient(#0051a5 0 0), #fff;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 60% 2.5px, 2.5px 60%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease;
  }
  
  .sign {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    margin-right: 1em;
  }
  
  .tilelabel {
    grid-area: sample;
    font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #fff;
    padding-left: 1em;
    height: 2em;
  }
  
  .tileaccent {
    color: #FFC72C;
  }
  
  .hidden-text {
    grid-area: extratext;
    display: none;
    font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    background-color: #F5F5F4;
    color: #000;
    margin: 1em;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    padding-left: 1em;
    border-radius: 1em;
  }
  
  .expanded>.hidden-text {
    display: block;
    animation: fade-in 1s;
  }
  
  @keyframes fade-in {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
  
  @keyframes fade-out {
    from {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    to {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
  
  .hidden-text ul li ul {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .hidden-text ul li.active ul {
    display: block;
  }
  
  li .plus {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  
  li.active .plus {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  /* Changes the cursor to a pointer for the list items that have a child ul */
  
  .hidden-text ul li:has(ul) .plus {
    float: right;
  }
  
  .hidden-text ul li:has(ul) {
    list-style: none;
    /* Remove the default bullet point */
  }
  
  .hidden-text ul li:has(ul) {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="tilecontainer">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="plus sign"></div>
      <div class="tilelabel">text<span class="tileaccent"> text</span></div>
      <div class="hidden-text">
        <ul>
          <a href="">text</a>
          <li>text
            <div class="plus sign"></div>
            <ul>
              <a href="">text</a>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <a href="">text</a>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <a href="">text</a>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <a href="">text</a>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tilecontainer">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="plus sign"></div>
      <div class="tilelabel">text<span class="tileaccent"> text</span></div>
      <div class="hidden-text">
        <ul>
          <a href="">text</a>
          <li>text
            <div class="plus sign"></div>
            <ul>
              <a href="">text</a>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <a href="">text</a>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <a href="">text</a>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <a href="">text</a>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tilecontainer">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="plus sign"></div>
      <div class="tilelabel">text<span class="tileaccent"> text</span></div>
      <div class="hidden-text">
        <ul>
          <a href="">text</a>
          <li>text
            <div class="plus sign"></div>
            <ul>
              <a href="">text</a>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <a href="">text</a>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <a href="">text</a>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <a href="">text</a>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tilecontainer">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="plus sign"></div>
      <div class="tilelabel">text<span class="tileaccent"> text</span></div>
      <div class="hidden-text">
        <ul>
          <a href="">text</a>
          <li>text
            <div class="plus sign"></div>
            <ul>
              <a href="">text</a>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <a href="">text</a>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <a href="">text</a>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <a href="">text</a>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tilecontainer">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="plus sign"></div>
      <div class="tilelabel">text<span class="tileaccent"> text</span></div>
      <div class="hidden-text">
        <ul>
          <a href="">text</a>
          <li>text
            <div class="plus sign"></div>
            <ul>
              <a href="">text</a>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <a href="">text</a>
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <a href="">text</a>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <a href="">text</a>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tilecontainer">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="plus sign"></div>
      <div class="tilelabel">text <span class="tileaccent">text</span></div>
      <div class="hidden-text">
        <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
          <li><a href="">text</a></li>
          <li><a href="">text</a></li>
          <li><a href="">text</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```